# Can you use the integral test on the positive part of an alternating series, and then conclude that the alternating series converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Here is a question from my calc test:
Consider the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n a_n $ where $a_n$ is positive for all n, Which of the following guarantees that the series converges?

Option 1:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx$$ converges, where $f(n)=a_n$ for all $n$.

Option 2:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$$

My calc teacher says that option 1 is incorrect because "you can't use integral test on alternating series", but I don't think that makes sense because if the positive part of the alternating series converges, then it implies that the alternating series converges absolutely. In other words, if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges by the integral test, then so does the alternating series form of the series. I don't see how his logic doesn't apply to the ratio test either, because we are only considering $a_n$ for both tests, and $a_n>0$ so both should work.

Is my calc teacher right?

Comment: First, when you say "the positive part of the alternating series", that would refer to just the positive terms - which are the even terms the way you have written it. Better to say "the series of absolute values", which the rest of your question is about.

Comment: If a series converges absolutely, then it converges.  You seem to be using the integral test to show that the series converges absolutely.  Hence...?

Comment: thats what i'm trying to convince my teacher, but nevertheless he doesn't agree that the integral test can be applied in this way

Comment: Did you omit a premise that $f$ is decreasing? That’s part of the usual integral test. If it isn’t, it could be anything and the convergence of the interval wouldn’t imply anything.

Comment: if f is positive and convergent, doesn't it imply that it decreases

Comment: @OPRESTON No.  Consider the sequence $1/2, -1, 1/4, -1/3, 1/6, -1/5, \dotsc$.

Comment: For any positive sequence $\{a_n\}$, the function $$f(x) = \begin{cases}a_n&x = n\\0&x \ne n\end{cases}$$ satisfies both $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx = 0$ and $f(n) = a_n$ for all $n$. But there are many positive sequences  $\{a_n\}$ for which $\sum_n (-1)^na_n$ does not converge. I invite you to consider why adding the conditions that $f$ be positive itself and continuous would not fix this. The additional restriction that $f$ must be decreasing (and therefore $\{a_n\}$ must be decreasing) is required. But this is not provided in the assumptions of the question.

Comment: if we allow ourselves to use any arbitrary piecewise function, doesn't that defeat the point of the question, for example, what if a function was defined for only every other integer, the a of n+1 would not exist and the ratio test would not work. But idk and it doesnt really matter thanks for the help

Comment: @OPRESTON What do you mean by $a_n$ "doesn't exist"?  For each $n$, there *is* an $n$-th term, though that term can be zero.  But, yes, if *any* function can be used in the integral test, then things don't work the way you want them to.  That is, it seems, exactly the problem with the question you are asking.  What are the hypotheses of the integral test?  What needs to be true in order for that test to apply?